# Does it matter if I slaughter the lost lambs?

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

I've received the quest **Lost Lambs**, and it seems as if for each of the three guys I'm sent to stop, I have the option of fighting them or letting them go.

Other than the potential experience/loot from defeating them in combat, is there any difference in the quest or later on in the game between killing them or letting them go?

Comment: You will lose the war because you won't get the Sheppard as War Asset. Yeah, I show myself out, thank you.